# Xamarin Form(PCL) IOS Firebase Push Message not working

Tags: c#, firebase, push-notification, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a xamarin form project and I integrated firebase push notification in both Android & IOS projects. Its working fine on Android but not working with iOS.
I downloaded and added GoogleService-info.plist in iOS project, Set its Build Action to BundleResource.

AppDelegates.cs

```
    namespace PushNotification.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            RegisterForNotificationFCM();

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }


        private void RegisterForNotificationFCM()
        {

            //Firebase Cloud Messaging Configuration

            //Get permission for notification
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // iOS 10
                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

                Messaging.SharedInstance.RemoteMessageDelegate = this as IMessagingDelegate;

            }
            else
            {
                // iOS 9 <=
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            Firebase.Analytics.App.Configure();

            Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh((sender, e) =>
            {
                var newToken = Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newToken);

                connectFCM();
            });

        }


        public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Disconnect();
        }

        public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            connectFCM();
            base.OnActivated(uiApplication);
        }

        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken, Firebase.InstanceID.ApnsTokenType.Prod);
        }

        //Fire when background received notification is clicked
        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            //Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(userInfo);

            // Generate custom event
            NSString[] keys = { new NSString("Event_type") };
            NSObject[] values = { new NSString("Recieve_Notification") };
            var parameters = NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>.FromObjectsAndKeys(keys, values, keys.Length);

            // Send custom event
            Firebase.Analytics.Analytics.LogEvent("CustomEvent", parameters);

            if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(userInfo);
                var aps_d = userInfo["aps"] as NSDictionary;
                var alert_d = aps_d["alert"] as NSDictionary;
                var body = alert_d["body"] as NSString;
                var title = alert_d["title"] as NSString;
                debugAlert(title, body);
            }
        }

        private void connectFCM()
        {
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Connect((error) =>
            {
                if (error == null)
                {
                    Messaging.SharedInstance.Subscribe("/topics/topicName");
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error != null ? "error occured" : "connect success");
            });
        }

        private void debugAlert(string title, string message)
        {
            var alert = new UIAlertView(title ?? "Title", message ?? "Message", null, "Cancel", "OK");
            alert.Show();
        }


    }
}
```

Added all required Firebase libraries in IOS project & its building fine. But notification is not receiving on IOS simulator. Tell me what I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED

I had this same problem and was dealing with it for a day or two. The problem came down to the selected provisioning profile that was being used. When I changed my app id in the apple development portal to use push notification and downloaded my provisioning profile it created a second profile with the same name downloaded. This caused an error when it tried to select the correct one. Deleted the old provisioning profile and all is well now.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot test push notification in the simulator**

Please take a look on the [Prerequisites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device).

```
For Cloud Messaging:

 - A physical iOS device 
 - APNs certificate with Push Notifications enabled
 - In Xcode, enable Push Notifications in App > Capabilities
```

Comment: Ok, But things i mentioned above are okay?

Comment: I believe you should really test it on an actually physical device to confirm the  expected result

Comment: @Burhan Firebase Push Messages is a (binding) library for Xamarin. If the original library (for Native iOS) doesn't work on the simulator for messages then neither the Xamarin Library will. I dont think there is any reason to add it to the docs unless the functionality is different

Comment: I got your point but i check it on device its still not pushing?

Comment: What am i missing ?